# server side paging with business logic filtering

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005, pagination

i need to show total number of rows at the grid title.
the grid have to deal also with large amount of records.
so i decide to use grid custom paging feature.
i know how to do server side paging with sql2005 ROW_NUMBER etc.
but my difficulty is with the complex row base filtering done at the business logic layer.
i think that doing first the complex filtering (in order to know the items count) on the large amount of records will be not efficient and maybe can cause out of memory exception.

right now this project (asp.net web app) is on production with .net framework1.1,sql2005.
next version on production will be with .net framework4.0.
after that we will upgrade to sql2008.

please help me to find a solution for that problem?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would say if you are afraid of Out of Memory exceptions in production either the HW is undersized for the amount of data you have or your code is really badly wrong :)

I would have everything done is a store procedure, including filtering, paging and sorting. Once you have this sorted out in the server and you have specified the page size and pag index you need to retrieve, the stored proc simply returns the single page of records you are looking for already sorted as well and you can bind this to your UI controls.

Is this what you wanted or did I get you wrong?

Comment: but the filtering is to complex to put it in a stored proc.

Comment: then has to be simplified, can you show some examples on how you filter editing your question?

Comment: the filtering code is written in c# in a security module. it's for row base security filtering by the userProfileID parameter and a set of permissions define for each profile.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using .net 4.0, IQueryable is a viable option. See [here](http://thinkbeforecoding.com/post/2009/01/19/Repositories-and-IQueryable-the-paging-case) for details. Basically, IQueryable delays the execution of the query so you can apply the business logic and then fetch *relevant* data from the underlying data store (sql server in your case).
But, I would do some micro-benchmarking of the query performance before going down this route.

Comment: the problem is that after the fetch from DB i am filtering the results according to some security business rules logic written in c# so some of the records need to be removed from the result set, so the total rows counter need to substract those rows that were removed from the result set.

Comment: Can you paste some sample code of the filtering being done in your business layer?